# Different version code for APK, android app with phonegap build

Tags: java, android, cordova, google-play

When I trying to upload my app on google play, this errormessage is displayed:

```
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.
```

Im downloading my APK from my phonegap build.

My question is:

In what file can I change the version number?

I have tried to change in androidmanifest.xml, Version code and Version name

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When uploading to PhoneGap Build, the manifest file isn't included. Try changing the version and versionCode attributes in PhoneGap's config.xml instead.

Answer (score 8):

You should specify the version code attribute in the "config.xml", Note that version code attribute should be like that android-versionCode="2" , as shown in below example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="ca.anything.anything.any"
    android-versionCode="2"
    version="1.0.3"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets">
    <name>Application Name</name>
....
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have to set app version in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: In AdroidManifest.xml you have Version code  and Version number like this:

  android:versionName="1.0-DEVELOPMENT"
    android:versionCode="1"

Is that what you mean? Because thats is what I have changed.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I should have mentioned - versionCode is an integer(at least I increase by 1), while version name is visible to the user( thus making 1.0.1 for a bugfix is a good idea )